# onActivityResult not giving any results

Tags: java, android, image, browser, android-activity

I have coded an Image Browse class which lets the user choose an image, but i cannot get any path for the Image. onActivityResult is not giving any result. I tried with Log.v to check but with no success.

First Class:

```
showImg = new ImageView(context);
showImg.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
showImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Select image
        BrowsePicture select = new BrowsePicture(context);

        Log.v("BrowsePictureSSS", ""+select.filemanagerstring);
        Log.v("BrowsePictureSSS", ""+select.selectedImagePath);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(select.filemanagerstring);
        showImg.setImageBitmap(bMap);

        }
    });
```

BrowseImage Class:

```
package com.FWilson.MyFavoritePlaces;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
public class BrowsePicture extends Activity {

private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;

protected String selectedImagePath;

protected String filemanagerstring;

public BrowsePicture(Activity context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    context.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    setResult(0);
}
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

            //OI FILE Manager
            filemanagerstring = selectedImageUri.getPath();

            //MEDIA GALLERY
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

            //DEBUG PURPOSE - you can delete this if you want
            if(selectedImagePath!=null)
                Log.v("BrowsePic", ""+selectedImagePath);
            else System.out.println("selectedImagePath is null");
            if(filemanagerstring!=null)
                Log.v("BrowsePic", ""+filemanagerstring);
            else System.out.println("filemanagerstring is null");

            //NOW WE HAVE OUR WANTED STRING
            if(selectedImagePath!=null) {

            }
            else {


            }

        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null)
    {
        int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
    else return null;
}
}
```

Comment: Is your 'first class' the class that is being started by BrowseImage?  It would help to get a little more information as to what each class is doing and where they fit into the flow of your application.

Comment: No, "First Class" starts the Browse Image, as you can see in the OnClick method:  BrowsePicture select = new BrowsePicture(context)

Comment: Your understanding of how Android works appears to be flawed.  You, the developer, do not instantiate Activities yourself.  This is done by the Android Activity Framework.  You simply implement the lifecycle callbacks provided by the Android Activity Framework.  See my answer below for relevant links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your BrowsePicture activity lacks an onCreate() method. You might have better results if you remove your constructor completely and place the code it currently has in onCreate() -- this is what is appropriate for an Activity overload.

Comment: But this is not the main Activity, can you tell me how to start BrowsePicture from another class?

Comment: Nvm, i found how to start from another class, worked like charm with your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your first setResult(0) in BrowsePicture constructor doesn't seem useful. Your call to super.onActivity neither.

log the values of params of onActivity to see what happens.

Regards,
Stéphane

Comment: i did remove setResult and super.onActity, and placed logs, but i am not getting any response.

Comment: I agree with @mah, it should be in onCreate method.

Comment: and use @Override when  you override a method like onActivityResult so that compiler can check that there is no method signature problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [Android Activity Lifecycle as defined in the class overview for the Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  You will see that you should not be instantiating Activities yourself, but that you should be implementing the lifecycle callbacks that Android has provided.

It appears that you are already using some of the other Android callbacks available properly, (`onActivityResult()`) you just need to also work with the lifecycle callbacks.